# Graph Execution Error: Table not initialized when calling model.fit

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm attempting to fit my model to training data, but getting the following error.

```py
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.FailedPreconditionError: Graph execution error:

Table not initialized.
         [[{{node text_vectorization/string_lookup/None_Lookup/LookupTableFindV2}}]]
         [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_train_function_1156]
```

The '.classes/train' directory contains two folders each with one text file. They are simple phrases.  Following this [tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/load_data/text), I am attempting to train a model to classify based on text.

```
classes
└── train
    ├── class1
    │   └── class1.txt
    └── class2
        └── class2.txt
```

My code is as below:

```py
def train(vocab_size=10):
    
    def vectorize_text(text, label):
        text = tf.expand_dims(text, -1)
        return vectorize_layer(text), label

    with open('allData.json', 'r') as file:
        json_data = json.load(file)

    raw_train_ds = tf.keras.utils.text_dataset_from_directory('./classes/train')
   
    vectorize_layer = tf.keras.layers.TextVectorization(
        output_mode='int',
    )
    train_ds = raw_train_ds.map(vectorize_text)   
    train_text = raw_train_ds.map(lambda text, labels : text)
    vectorize_layer.adapt(train_text)
    

    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Embedding(vocab_size, 64, mask_zero=True))
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(64, 5, padding="valid", activation="relu", strides=2)) 
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D())
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(2))

    model.compile(
        loss=tf.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
        optimizer='adam',
        metrics=['accuracy']
        )
    
    AUTOTUNE = tf.data.AUTOTUNE

    def configure_dataset(dataset):
        return dataset.cache().prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)

    train_ds = configure_dataset(train_ds)
    history = model.fit(train_ds) #this causes the error, apparently
```